# How to define exit point for Docker Stop

Tags: docker

I'm running an Application in tomcat. It generate some application's temp files during the process. And when we shutdown the tomcat using `shutdown.sh` or stop tomcat from IntelliJ then temp files will be converted to csv. This is inbuilt feature of my Application.

Now when I run the same Application in Docker, then temp is not converting to csv format as I expect it to.

I can see `ENTERYPOINT` in Docker configuration file that indicates the startup script for the docker. I don't know how `docker stop` internally works and what it trigger when we execute `docker stop <container Name>`, or where I should define the script for docker stop.

I also tried `docker stop -t 10 <container Name>`, with the thought in my mind that it might be tomcat, taking time to shutdown hence docker might be killing the tomcat process. So I tried `docker stop` with 10 second time also. But no luck.

I think docker is killing the tomcat when I execute `docker stop`

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you also show what the Dockerfile contains? So that we have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I can't share all details but the parameters are related to ENV,FROM, RUN , COPY, WORKDIR and ENTERYPOINT.

ENTERYPOINT has one script name

Comment: [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) sends the main container process (that is, the `ENTRYPOINT`) SIGTERM, and after 10 seconds, SIGKILL.  The workflow you describe sounds a little odd; what happens if the server gets OOM-killed and never gets a chance to clean up?  Can you provide any sort of [mcve] beyond a listing of Dockerfile directives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check this [reference](https://dzone.com/articles/stopping-docker-containers-gracefully-3) for process with pid 1.

Step to perform in your system.
Step 1 :- in entrypoint check your script file.
Step 2 :- update your script line entry.sh, find some line where you're starting your tomcat.
Step 3 :- for start tomcat use "exec sh catalina.sh run".
Step 4 :- check your ps with "docker exec  ps -ef" it must be run on pid 1
Step 5 :- rebuild docker image.
Step 6 :- docker stop  will send shutdown signal to tomcat and works.

For observe logs use docker logs -f <container_name>